# Query with multiple date range query

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlperformance

I have to collect data from one table base on date range.
Right now am using multiple select query to get this count
Ex

```
Select  @count1 =  count(*) 
from table
where  createddate between @date1 and @date2 and status in (1,2)

Select  @count2 =  count(*) 
from table
where  createddate between @date2 and @date3 and status in (3,4)

Select @count23 =  count(*) 
from table
where  createddate between @date3 and @date4 and status in (5,6)

Select count1, count2, count3
```

How to merge all above 3 queries? Will it increase performance?

Comment: Please describe what performance problems you experiencing? Maybe you could provide some figures. Did you try to analyze the query plan?

Comment: Why would combining them increase performance? What is your performance now? What do you expect? What amount of data is there? What are the indexes in your table?

Comment: like this we have 40 +  individual sql query and most of the condition is based on status like

This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful
I have to collect data from one table base on date range. Right now am using multiple select query to get this count Ex

status in (1,2)
status NOT in (1,2)
all re repeated table with diff condition

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN createdate BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2 AND [Status] IN (1,2) THEN 1 END) AS Count1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN createdate BETWEEN @Date2 AND @Date3 AND [Status] IN (3,4) THEN 1 END) AS Count2
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: And Count3? Exercise for OP?

Comment: Should be easy enough for them to work out, @DaleK . They need to understand the solution to implement it in the first place anyway, so it's a good "test" for them too.